# optional project resources without using targets

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there a way in xcode to have a specific resource (in this case a video file) be optional in a build somehow? just not using the file in your code is one thing, but to have the movie file excluded from the copy bundle list in the build phase is another thing...

i would prefer to not create another target due to the fact this project has a couple of targets already, and duplicating all of them is not ideal, but will probably be my last resort.

any suggestions how to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom build configuration (eg. ReleaseNoMovie) then add a "Run Script" to your build phases that removes a resource based on the selected build configuration:

```
if [ "$CONFIGURATION" == "ReleaseNoMovie" ]; then
rm "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/myMovie.mov"
fi
```